# iPhone is not finding Outlook calendars from other profiles

Tags: iphone, ms-office, calendar

I am trying to sync an iPhone 3GS with Outlook calendars on my PC (Windows XP, MS Office Professional Plus 2010).

In Outlook we have several profiles set up for different emails. At first the sync didn't appear to be working - until I realised that iTunes was syncing with the calendar from the default Outlook profile.

On the Info tab of iTunes only one calendar is listed under "Selected calendars". Similarly, only the email from the default profile is shown under "Sync mail accounts" section (though I'm not intending to sync mail).

How do I get iTunes to see the calendars from other profiles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out in the end. I simply set the other profile as the default and synced the calendar.

I have left it as the default for now, but a comment buried in a forum thread somewhere said that even if you set the original profile back to default, iTunes will continue synchronizing with the original (non-default) calendar.